# help on supplementary exercise for cycling

Tags: running, exercise, cardio, bicycling

so my question is pretty simple basically im a relative beginner at biking and was wondering what some good form of exercise would be on the days im not cycling thats not too taxing so i can still rest

currently i bike for about an hour every monday, wednesday and friday and is looking for something to fill in on my tuesdays and thursdays with weekends being mostly for rest depending on how i feel

i was thinking of a short run and some easy exercises like lunges push ups and such but not sure what would be too taxing as i can steel feel my legs being somewhat heavy on the days after a bike run

also i am mostly looking at this from the perspective of being healthy, loosing weight and getting better at biking as i go along

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to exercise to improve your cycling on days you will not cycle, it is best to do some aerobic work. I am usually a runner so my choice of cross training is biking because it is a lower impact on my joints,  but because you want an alternative to biking, I would recommend swimming, or an easy short run. You can do laps in the pool, or do an "aqua jog". This will help maintain your aerobic fitness on off days while not being as hard on your legs. Another option would be to do rowing, or really any type of cardio that is fun for you. As long as you aren't pushing too hard, almost any exercise can be a good substitute to give your body a break. If you want to do strength work, doing push-ups, lunges, jump squats etc is useful because it improves coordination and general strength which will help you from getting injured
Another important factor is what kind of volume you are doing on the bike. If you don't build up your volume slowly you will feel tired and slow after a couple of weeks.

Comment: ty for the answer i might start using running and some easy strength exercises on off days from now on then

Answer (score -1):

Many rivers and canals have cycling tracks or narrow roads one or both sides. These are the most joyful and refreshing cycling routes especially starting in morning. Usually both sides of river/canal there are farms with various plants growing. Nature's fragrance combined with sounds of birds and beauty of nature makes me forgetful of being tired and I cherish by best times riding such routes along rivers and canals.